# Can I chain a null check in a stream for List

Tags: java

New to Java. I'm trying to find a value in a List by using a stream - but I need to check whether the list is null before extracting a value and I am looking for how to chain that within the stream. Here's my current code:

```
for (Record currRec : records) {
        notedRec = masterRecs.stream().filter(rec -> rec.getId().equals(currRec.getId()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList()).get(0);
}
```

This code will fail if the *.collect()* returns null because I'm trying to *.get(0)* on a a List that could be null. I'm trying this approach now but it seems old and am looking for something more elegant:

```
for (Record currRec : records) {
recList = masterRecs.stream().filter(rec -> rec.getId().equals(currRec.getId()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        if(recList.size() > 0) {
            notedRec = recList.get(0);
        }else {
            // throw warning that record wasn't found in List
        }
}
```

To me it seems like I could chain the null check after the *.collect()* but I couldn't find anything on how to do that. Thanks for any helpful tips.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for `findFirst` and `orElseThrow`

```
masterRecs.stream().filter(rec -> rec.getId().equals(currRec.getId()))
                   .findFirst().orElseThrow(//some exception);
```

Comment: this approach removes the need for me to call .collect(Collectors.toList()) because it already does the job of fetching the first element?

Comment: `collect(Collectors.toList())` is collecting all element that satisfy the filter condition, `findFirst` will give you the first match element by terminating rest of stream @fumeng and i feel that's what you need